# Horizontally aligning blocks on text baseline

Tags: html, css, layout, typography

I have the following HTML code:

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I am looking to turn this into a single line on the top of my web page by floating right the `<nav>`.

However, because the `<h1>` has a much bigger font size than the `<li>` elements the text gets misaligned. **I want the elements to be aligned on the baseline.** In a picture:

[image: Visual description.]

Note the red line for the baseline. This is what I have right now:

```css
#float, #nofloat { width: 300px; }

ul, h1, nav, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

nav { display: inline-block; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
ul > li { display: inline; }
ul > li:after { content: " | "; }
ul > li:last-child:after { content: ""; }

#float nav { float: right; }
```

```html
<p>Everything is aligned to baseline before floating:</p>
<div id="nofloat">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<p>But after floating it's messed up:</p>
<div id="float">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why my question _'does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful'_?

Comment: Hard to say why the down vote; your question is well posed, concise and shows a snippet/effort.  Perhaps there is a similar question in the SO archive, but try searching for it...

Comment: @MarcAudet I did search for duplicates, there were similar questions, but none that tried to align the text inside the blocks on the baseline. Regardless, if it's a duplicate, that's not a valid reason to downvote - the close button is for that (or flag button if you don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Sometimes, finding a pre-existing solution on SO is like finding a needle in a haystack; similar questions can be worded in such different ways that they would never come up in a search, no matter how creative your search terms are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `text-align:right` to your `nav` if you have a fixed `width`

```css
#float,
#nofloat {
  width: 300px;
}

ul,
h1,
nav,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width:auto;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline;
}
ul > li:after {
  content: " | ";
}
ul > li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
#float nav {
 text-align:right
}
```

```html
<p>Everything is aligned to baseline before floating:</p>
<div id="nofloat">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<p>But after floating it's messed up:</p>
<div id="float">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Plus since `inline-block` has gap issues (fixable) you can use use `display:table/table-cell`

```css
#float,
#nofloat {
  width: 300px;
  display: table;
}

ul,
h1,
nav,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width:auto;
}
nav {
  display: table-cell;
  width:200px
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline;
}
ul > li:after {
  content: " | ";
}
ul > li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
#float nav {
 text-align:right
}
```

```html
<p>Everything is aligned to baseline before floating:</p>
<div id="nofloat">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<p>But after floating it's messed up:</p>
<div id="float">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: The `nav` doesn't have a fixed width. But using your answer I made this, which seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dnzdvwjo/ .

Comment: Yes thats the other solution, applying the `display:table` to `nav`  parent instead `nav` grand parent, if you didnt wnt to use fixed `width` on your `nav`.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML mark-up lends itself to a solution using CSS tables.

Apply `display: table` to `header`, and set the width to 100% which will force it to take on the width of the parent container.

Apply `display: table-cell` to `nav` and set `width: 1%` to force it to have a shrink-to-fit width.  To prevent text wrapping, set `white-space: nowrap`.

This will work fine as long as your title can fit in the remaining space, but you can probably adjust the details based on your layout.

```css
#float, #nofloat { width: 300px; }

ul, h1, nav, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

nav { display: inline-block; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
ul > li { display: inline; }
ul > li:after { content: " | "; }
ul > li:last-child:after { content: ""; }

header {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

#float header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /* the parent div has a width */
}

#float nav { 
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%; /* forces this cell to shrink-to-fit */
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Everything is aligned to baseline before floating:</p>
<div id="nofloat">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<p>But after floating it's messed up:</p>
<div id="float">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this compare to the solution I found in response to dippas's answer? https://jsfiddle.net/dnzdvwjo/ The 1% width and `white-space` seems hacky compared to my solution.

Comment: Essentially the same, dippas posted his solution while I was working on my answer, so we both came up with the same technique.  The only difference is that I handle the table-cell width a bit differently.